# Need help figuring out how to capture and display a C type struct value in a C# WinForms GUI

Tags: c#, c, winforms, struct

I have a C program that will display the UDP data being captured from port 51020. The UDP packets are structs and the data that I would like to focus on is a field within a struct that I will need to point to. Basically this will be a real time display. First thing is that I need guidance on creating a C like struct in C# and two how would I be able to access and display the data captured onto a label or textbox on a GUI in C#.

The C like struct that I am referencing is:

```
typedef struct DD_DATAGRM {
    unsigned long LENGTH;
    unsigned long ABCD_Frame;
    unsigned long CHANNEL[256];
    unsigned char STATUS[256];
    unsigned long CRC32;
} DATAGRAM;
```

```
**DATAGRAM recv_data**
```

To get the data desired I would use the following syntax in C:

```
*(float*)&recv_data.CHANNEL[0]
```

The code for the simple C# program I currently have is:

*Form1.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace UDP_Recv
{
    
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {

       UdpClient Client = new UdpClient(51020); // port number
       string data = "";
    
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }


       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

           try
           {
               Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               richTextBox1.Text += ex.Message.ToString();
           }
       }

       void recv(IAsyncResult res)
       { 

           IPEndPoint RemoteIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 60240);
           byte[] received = Client.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIP);
           data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received);
         
           //to avoid cross-threading we use Method Invoker
           this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
           {
               richTextBox1.Text += "\nReceived data: " + data;
           }));

           Client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
       }
    }}
```

I need help creating a struct that will be received on port 51020 and display on a textbox or label in C#. Also to be able to point to a specific field in the struct to access the value within the array. I'm new to C# and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://pinvoke.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people are not going to like this but it should work

```
       const int SIZE = 8 + 8 + 2048 + 256 + 8;
        public class DD_DATAGRM
        {
            public ulong LENGTH { get; set; }
            public ulong ABCD_Frame { get; set; }
            public ulong[] CHANNEL = new ulong[256];
            public string STATUS = "";
            public ulong CRC32 { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] received = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
            List<DD_DATAGRM> ChannelBase = new List<DD_DATAGRM>();

            //check the receive data is multiple of DD_DATAGRM
            if (received.Length % SIZE != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < received.Length; i += SIZE)
                {
                    DD_DATAGRM newDataGRM = new DD_DATAGRM();
                    newDataGRM.LENGTH = BitConverter.ToUInt64(received, i);
                    newDataGRM.ABCD_Frame = BitConverter.ToUInt64(received, i + 8);
                    for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
                    {
                        newDataGRM.CHANNEL[j] = BitConverter.ToUInt64(received, (8 * j) + 16);
                    }
                    int location = Array.IndexOf(received, (byte)'\0', 2064);
                    newDataGRM.STATUS = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received, 2064, location - 2064);
                    newDataGRM.CRC32 = BitConverter.ToUInt64(received, i + 2320);
                    ChannelBase.Add(newDataGRM);
                }
            }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Frame", typeof(ulong));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
            for (int col = 0; col < 256; col++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(col.ToString(), typeof(ulong));
            }

            foreach (DD_DATAGRM gram in ChannelBase)
            {
                List<object> rowData = new List<object>();
                rowData.Add(gram.ABCD_Frame);
                rowData.Add(gram.STATUS);
                rowData.AddRange(gram.CHANNEL.Cast<List<object>>());
                dt.Rows.Add(rowData);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is a long 32 or 64 bits? Looks like it is a CRC32 so long may only be 32 bit.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response and the long is 64 bits. So would I implement your code into the public partial class Form1 : Form area of .cs file?

Comment: The original `channel` was array of longs, so would be 256*8 bytes (or 256*4, if 32bit)

Comment: It doesn't matter where the code is located as long as you get the entire message before processing.  It is very suspicious that a CRC32 is 64 bits.

Comment: I just found one error.  The Array Copy for long should be 256 and not 2048.  The size is the number of integers not bytes.

Comment: I just realized you can't use Array copy to copy from bytes to ulong.  Needed another loop.

Comment: @jdweng 64bits is the length I read for the device that I am receiving data from. I appreciate your help. I'm not sure if you would be able to help with this other area but, would you know how to access the CHANNEL field and display the value on a label or textbox when a form opens? I am trying to do this through an event handler such as  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: I added code above to add channel to a datatable.  You can then make the table the datasource of a DGV.

Comment: I suggest using structure instead of class, Then remove `SIZE` constant and use `sizeof`.
It will easy to add fields to the structure, And easy if there was calling method from C